# Where is the code that does floating-point division for C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, divide-by-zero

#### Question

I would like to see the piece of code that does a floating-point division and returns `Infinity` when dividing by zero. Where can I find it?

#### Code example

The motivation of wanting to know that comes from this code taken from the .NET documentation. I would have expected to get a `DivideByZeroException` but instead I get `Infinity`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      int number1 = 3000;
      int number2 = 0;

      Console.WriteLine((double)number1 / number2);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//        Infinity
```

#### Documentation

I found the documentation stating that floating-point division by zero does not throw an exception, so that's fine:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

> Dividing a floating-point value by zero doesn't throw an exception; it
>   results in positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a number
>   (NaN), according to the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic. Because the
>   following example uses floating-point division rather than integer
>   division, the operation does not throw a DivideByZeroException
>   exception.

#### Code in .NET Framework

In Visual Studio, I hovered over the "/" division sign and Resharper shows

```
double double.operator /(double left, double right)
```

And now, I'd like to see the implementation of that to see how that `Infinity` is returned. But I can't find it.

I checked here

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

but don't see the division operator.

The above link then lead me here

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-

but also nothing about the implementation detail.

I also looked here

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,428

but only see commented out code

```
///        Double IArithmetic<Double>.Divide(Double divisor, out bool overflowed) {
///            Double s = m_value / divisor;
///            overflowed = IsInfinity(s) || IsNaN(s);
///            return s;
///        }
```

Also nothing in the `Double` implementation of [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx):

- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Double.cs

I would have expected something liked this (pseudo code):

```
public static double operator /(double left, double right)
{
   if (right == 0)
   {
      return double.Infinity;
   }
   else
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to see the source, the ECMA specs should do. look up 14.7.2 Division operator..... There is a table telling you how its implemented

Comment: The implementation is in the. FPU, not a line of code. In either case it is an off-site resource and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Here is your source *fdivp* https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fdiv:fdivp:fidiv

Comment: @user207421: The Stack Overflow reason for closured related to offsite resources is for requests for **recommendations** for offsite resources because they attract opinions. It is not for queries about the **existence** of resources for which whether they apply to a certain request is a matter of fact, not opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles down to the following CIL:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       21 (0x15)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (int32 V_0,
           int32 V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4     0xbb8
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0008:  stloc.1
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  IL_000a:  conv.r8
  IL_000b:  ldloc.1
  IL_000c:  conv.r8
  IL_000d:  div
  IL_000e:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
  IL_0013:  nop
  IL_0014:  ret
} // end of method Example::Main
```

That `IL_000d:  div` call is the divide operation happening.  This means the CLR will perform the work, so you won't find any source code doing the work.  If we dig into the CLR source code (here showing the coreclr) for the divide operator for floating point values:

```
TFp FpDiv(TFp dividend, TFp divisor)
{
#ifdef _TARGET_ARMARCH_
    // From the ECMA standard:
    //
    // If [dividend] is zero and [divisor] is zero
    //   the result is NaN.
    // If [dividend] is infinity and [divisor] is infinity
    //   the result is NaN.

    if (dividend == 0 && divisor == 0)
    {
        return TFpTraits::NaN();
    }
    else if (!_finite(dividend) && !_isnan(dividend) && !_finite(divisor) && !_isnan(divisor))
    {
        return TFpTraits::NaN();
    }
#endif // _TARGET_ARMARCH_

    return dividend / divisor;
}
```

You can see it's handling some preconditions, then calling into the compiler's intrinsic operation.  On x86 that will in turn be a `FDIV` call, which is documented as raising a divide by zero flag, which the C runtime, thanks to IEEE 754, will turn into an infinity.  This infinity works it way back up the chain to your C# app.

Comment: Surely the C code would mask the #Z exception and let FDIV do the rest?